# Google maps not showing marker in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers

I following toturial given at `Google Developers` site and have this code in `MapsActivity.java`

```
package com.pro.soft.inzi.track_trace;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        Button sign_in_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        sign_in_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Live.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        Button history_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
        history_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), History.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

        // Add a marker in Pakistan and move the camera
        LatLng Pakistan = new LatLng(31, 71);
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Pakistan).title("Marker in Pakistan"));
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Pakistan));
    }
}
```

These are permissions in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <!--
 The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <!--
     To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <permission
        android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="your.package.name.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"/>
```

Everything is working fine Except a `Marker` I follow the question related in this site and instructions on web **But** all in vain.
**Marker is not showing in the map**
Please tell me what's wrong.

**Edit:** here is `activity_maps` code that include `MapFragment` in it

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b1_text"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b2_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b1"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/b3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/b3_text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/b2"/>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainP"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b2">

        <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/map"
            tools:context=".MapsActivity"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    </RelativeLayout>
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/info_1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainP"
        />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/info_2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/mainP"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/info"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should initialized your `googleMap Object` in `onCreate(....)`

```
 SupportMapFragment googleMap=(SupportMapFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Comment: I added this now But still `Marker` is not visible

Comment: in the above code you posted where to use `googleMap` of SupportMapFragment because when I hover over it tooltiptext show `variable googleMap is never used`

Comment: as`SupportMapFragment googleMap` or as `GoogleMap googleMap`

Comment: Adding marker while map is animating causes issues in some cases

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(Pakistan)
            .title("Marker in Pakistan")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` is not being called.
You need to call `getMapAsync` on the map fragment to set the `OnMapReadyCallback`

From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/SupportMapFragment.html#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))

> **public void getMapAsync (OnMapReadyCallback callback)**
>
> Sets a callback object which will be triggered when the GoogleMap
>   instance is ready to be used.

Add this code at the end of your `onCreate` function:

```
MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

Comment: when I add this in `onCreate()` the activity shows a dialog containing `Unfortunately MapsActivity has stop` why is this

Comment: @Inzimam Tariq IT it's hard to tell what the problem is without seeing the error, could you post your activity_maps.xml and the stack trace of the error?

Comment: I added my `activity_maps` code. It produce no error/stack trace But when activity starts a popup appears with `Unfortunately MapsActivity has stoped`

Comment: @Inzimam Tariq IT based on your activity_maps.xml I guess that your app is throwing a `ClassCastException`. I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
add this ,it works
```

googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions() .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("MY LOCATION") .snippet("kochi").draggable(true));